# After iOS update, can't get past splashscreen in ionic app

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, build, ionic3

Instead of launching my app, things stall here:

```
(lldb)     command script add -f fruitstrap_2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356.connect_command connect
(lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f fruitstrap_2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356.run_command run
(lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f fruitstrap_2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356.autoexit_command autoexit
    (lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f fruitstrap_2e5ac6066864be48322a757c4d0ccdfde52cf356.safequit_command safequit
(lldb)     connect
(lldb)     run
    success
(lldb)     safequit
Process 1762 detached
```

Normally the app loads after the output...but now it is just stuck on the splashscreen. I updated my iOS a few days ago...and haven't developed on it since then (I've been using my browser), but now I am trying to go back to my phone and this is happening - so I think it has something to do with the iOS update. I had this problem once before actually with this app...and it was because this line:

```
<script src="build/vendor.js"></script>
```

was missing from my `index.html` but I checked and it is there. Has anyone started having this problem with the update?

Here is my environment info:

```
cli packages: (/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myApp/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.0

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
    ios-sim    : 6.1.2 
    Node       : v7.7.3
    npm        : 4.1.2 
    OS         : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55 

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure `WiFi` is turned on, on your device :)